# How to list the installed shells available on MacBook?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

Is there a specific command to list the installed shells available on the machine via the terminal?

I know:

```
which bash
```

But it shows only the active bash shell.

Comment: Possibly `ls /bin/*sh`.

Comment: @JeffHolt, on modern MacOS that directory is read-only even to root, so anything installed with a 3rd-party package manager (MacPorts, Homebrew, Nix, etc) will be elsewhere.

Comment: (That said, the question is categorically off-topic; Stack Overflow is only for questions about _writing code_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cat /etc/shells` command to list the available shells on MACOS.